# Can I extend the allowed Vin range of a voltage detector IC with a simple zener shunt regulator?

Tags: zener, over-voltage-protection, voltage-detector

I'm trying to solve a particular corner case in the behaviour of a system I designed.

The issue can be boiled down to this: I don't want a particular LDO to operate if it's input voltage is below 4V (give or take, I can accept a 10% tolerance on this).

After some searching, I found that a good way to do this is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTTOrI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(obviously I'm omitting details like decoupling caps and such)

IC1 behaves like this:

- when Vin < 4.0V, the OUT pin will be at 0V, disabling the LDO
- when Vin > 4.0V, OUT = Vin, enabling the LDO
- there's a few % of hysteresis built-in, which I don't care about

## Problem

The BD49L40 can only handle Vin up to 10V. The input voltage in my system can go as high as 33V (the LDO is suitable, but IC1 isn't). There are higher-voltage-tolerant voltage detectors, which are several times as expensive, so I'm curious if I can avoid them.

Since the quiescent current of IC1 is 1-2µA, and the Enable pin on IC2 can source or sink 1-2.5µA as well, I need a micropower voltage limiter to the input of IC1 so that I don't kill it when Vin is >10V.

## Proposed solution

So I devised this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnLDqG.png)</sup>

In this case:

- If Vin=3V (for example), the zener does nothing, IC1 is powered through R1;
- If Vin=5V, the zener still doesn't conduct, IC1 sees close to 5V on its input pin, puts this on its OUT and enables the LDO;
- If Vin=16V, the zener conducts, limiting the voltage that IC1 sees to about 8 (or slightly less) volts. The voltage on the OUT/Enable pins is the same, about 8V. Since IC2 accepts anything above 2.0V as logic high, the discrepancy between IC2's Vin and Enable pins should not cause trouble.

## Question

This all seems acceptable, at least in theory. Is there anything I should be worried about? Anything that I may need to add to make it robust?

## EDIT

The question is mostly moot. I wasn't aware that the BD49xxx series had Pspice models available. I was able to simulate the thing and am now 99% sure it works as intended. The only non-obvious detail is that a small buffer cap on IC1's input is a must, it **cannot** function without it. 2-10nF seem to work well.

Comment: You're getting enough parts there that if you have a decent reference voltage on the board someplace, you may just want to use a comparator.  Googling "reset management IC" may also be fruitful, but I give no guarantees.

Comment: @TimWescott, the comparator is a good idea, but since at Vin=35 this will be the highest voltage in the system, the comparator will either have to be fed from Vin and support rail-to-rail inputs ($$), or I'll need a resistor divider, so the partcount is same, if not worse.

Comment: As per the search suggestion, of course there are thousands of reset/supervisor ICs and I may be missing something, but when I search in Digikey, Mouser, Farnell,etc. and select the high voltage range, even the cheapest suitable are >4x as expensive. Basically the BDxx parts are really cheap ($0.20/pc for 100) so very tempting in my case.

Comment: OK.  I admit, I'm feeling challenged now.  What about that jellybean of jellybeans, the LM393?  2-36V VCC range, the input operates down to 0V, and the output is open-collector, so plenty low.  You would need a divider on the input because the common mode only goes up to VCC-2V (so, more parts).  I'm strongly suspecting that your solution is perfectly good, BTW, I'm just responding to getting a kick in the assumptions.

Comment: That's fair enough, this kind of discussion is what I was hoping for when posting. The LM393 is also a viable solution, the same ballpark wrt price, and more conventional. Both inputs will require dividers in my case however.

Comment: @TimWescott, I updated the question with the results from a simulation.

Comment: @anrieff What if the zener fails, or fails to respond quickly enough? Anything you care about?

Comment: @jonk, fair point. IC2 is not a critical/first-priority component. If the zener fails and IC1 is toast, and assume IC2 doesn't work - a small functionality of the device will no longer work, but it's main function would be unaffected.